# In constructive set theory, is it consistent for there to be a ring that models smooth infinitesimal analysis?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, constructive-mathematics, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

In a constructive set theory such as CZF, it is consistent to assume that every function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. However, it is not consistent to assume that every such function is differentiable. CZF proves that the absolute value function exists and is a total function on $\mathbb R$.

But is it consistent to assume that there is some that there is *some* ring $R$ which models [smooth infinitesimal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis)?

Comment: Yes there's entire books about such models: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-4143-8

Comment: @MaxNew do those models show that *every* total function $R \mapsto R$ is differentiable, or just those in the model? My understanding is that those models just apply to functions "in the model", whereas I'm looking for a $R$ such that the axioms of SIA applies to all total functions. I may be misunderstanding though, since I'm not super familiar with the subject!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. How does a model distinguish between "every total function" and "every total function in the model [= itself]"?

Comment: The models in that book are non-trivial models of CZF + a ring R satisfying the principles of smooth infinitesimal analysis, e.g., that all total functions from R to R are differentiable. Since the model is non-trivial this proves that assuming one exists in CZF is consistent.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Christopher King seems to be asking something like "Is the first-order theory CZF + there is a structure (R,+,⋅,0,1) so that every function f:R→R obeys the Kock-Lawvere axiom consistent?" here, not "is there some topos where the SIA axioms stated at the level of the topos hold". I agree with his assessment that it at the very least need not be _immediate_ from the Moerdijk-Reyes topos models that the answer to this particular question is positive - e.g. does every topos w/ NNO model CZF?

Comment: @ChristopherKing: what is the difference between "*every* total function" and "just those in the model"? In any case, the topos validates thge *internal* statement "$\forall f \in R^R . \text{$f$ is smooth}$". Also, are you dead set on using CZF, or would higher-order intuitionistic logic also fit the bill?

Comment: @MaxNew oh, I was in the mindset of constructing a full model of SIA while working in CZF. But if the model satisfies CZF, that works as a consistency proof too!

Comment: @AndrejBauer hmm, I'd at least want something that's able to do a decent amount of set theory. I think HoTT (even without the univalence axiom) would work as well. I suppose the more interesting question is "what constructive principles/theories are compatible with SIA", but I was afraid that'd be a bit open ended.